# How to see the dictionary used to hold class/instance/attributes?

Tags: python

My colleague mentioned to me that the more classes/instances/their attributes I have in my application, the bigger **the dictionary** will get - so it is a good idea to write functions instead of creating a class when state management (or other specific need of making a class) is not needed.

I am trying to understand/visualize this **dictionary** used to hold the python classes/objects/attributes to understand the benefit as mentioned in above paragraph.

How to see the dictionary used to hold class/instance/attributes?

Following is some code I have written to check the type of 1) a class, 2) an instance of the class, 3) a function, 4) a function call, 5) list the contents of dir(). The output is:

```
Type of ClassA is:  <class 'type'>
Type of ins_a1 (class instance) is:  <class '__main__.ClassA'>
Type of func_a is:  <class 'function'>
Type of func_a() call is:  <class 'NoneType'>
dir() command:  ['ClassA', '__annotations__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__'
, 'func_a', 'ins_a1']
```

Code:

```
class ClassA:
    pass

def func_a():
    pass

print('Type of ClassA is: ', type(ClassA))
ins_a1 = ClassA()
print('Type of ins_a1 (class instance) is: ', type(ins_a1))

print('Type of func_a is: ', type(func_a))
print('Type of func_a() call is: ', type(func_a()))

print('dir() command: ', dir())
```

Comment: You're talking like there's one big dictionary used for all of that stuff throughout the whole program. There isn't; individual classes and instances have their own dicts for stuff specific to that class or instance.

Comment: How can I access that dictionary to visualize it please?

Comment: using `vars(whatever)`. Or directly, `whatever.__dict__` ... but again, there is no "the dictionary", there are potentially many dictionaries. This is only ever really an issue if you are creating many, many objects, say, `class Point:` with two attributes, `x` and `y`, and you need to handle millions of points. But you can use `__slots__` to avoid the creation of a `dict` as the namespace, and instead, it optimizes it as an array, although, you can no longer dynamically add attributes to objects of that class. All in all, this sounds like dubious advice as posed.

Comment: That being said, I also tend to advocate avoiding the use of classes when you aren't managing internal state. Of course, class-based programming is sort of the norm in a lot of software engineering, so often it is simply the default style so someone coming from another class-based OOP language can jump right in

Comment: I think that kind of advices lead to some kind of premature optimization, and if you don't precisely know the implementation details it can lead to "counter optimization". Plus, it looks as very low level optimization, applied to a high level language. That does really not feel that good when you go that way. Creating functions vs classes with methods should be dictated by the application design, with readability and maintainability in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the more you have toplevel objects in your module, the bigger the toplevel **dict** of your module will be. For example if I write this module:

```
class ClassA:
    pass

def func_a():
    pass

class ClassB():
    def method_1(self):
        pass

    def method_2(self):
        pass

    def method_3(self):
        pass
```

Then I get:

```
>>> import test
>>> dir(test)
['ClassA', 'ClassB', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'func_a']
>>> test.__dict__.keys()
dict_keys(['__name__', '__doc__', '__package__', '__loader__', '__spec__', '__file__', '__cached__', '__builtins__', 'ClassA', 'func_a', 'ClassB'])
```

Whereas if I had toplevel functions instead of `ClassB`'s methods, I would have 3 more elements in the modules's `__dict__`.
Instead the methods are in the class's `__dict__`:

```
>>> test.ClassB.__dict__.keys()
dict_keys(['__module__', 'method_1', 'method_2', 'method_3', '__dict__', '__weakref__', '__doc__'])
```

Furthermore, [according to this page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#dict), dict access in python is O(1) in time complexity on average, so the size of the dict will not affect performances.

So if I understood correctly what your colleague said, I would say that this advice is not wise. Where he is right in my opinion is that if you do need a class, then do not create one, but that is a matter of software design, not optimization.

Comment: The function is also of type Class, yet it does not make use of dict. Probably this is because function is implemented differently.

Comment: the function is not of type class, it is of type function, but the type function is a class indeed

Comment: @variable um, `function` type objects (i.e. functions) definitely **do** use a `__dict__`. Note, `Class` isn't a type, it's `type`, which all class/type objects inherit from (it is the base metaclass).